# How to run a test for a single function on a hdf5

Tags: c++, hdf5

I am trying to test tarray.cpp. I know you can use cmake, but I need to use G++ for a project. I just need to test the tarray portion and its dependencies. I put the tarray and all its dependencies in the same folder. However, when I try to compile it, I get this error:

```
$ g++ tarray.cpp -o tarray
```

In file included from H5Cpp.h:18:0, from tarray.cpp:28:

```
H5Include.h:15:10: fatal error: hdf5.h: No such file or directory

#include <hdf5.h>
          ^~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I have the hdf5 in the same folder, so I do not know why it does not detect it.

Comment: Try `#include "hdf5.h"`. Angle brackets mean search in system directories, and double quotes mean search in current directory too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `#include <hdf5.h>` to `#include "hdf5.h"`.

See [What is the difference between #include  and #include “filename”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21593/5763413).

The quotes around the `#include` will check in the current directory, while the angle brackets will check the include path.